# SQL Query for a view table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Frigorifero` table that has the function of a storage table, it contains an `ingredient_id` and `quantity` available for that ingredient.

```
CREATE TABLE FRIGORIFERO
(
    INGREDIENTE_ID INTEGER,
    QTA_DISP INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (INGREDIENTE_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (INGREDIENTE_ID) 
        REFERENCES INGREDIENTE(INGREDIENTE_ID)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Another table would be the `Piatto_Ing` that has a plate's_id and its corresponding required ingredients to make, another column is the quantity required for each ingredient.

```
CREATE TABLE PIATTO_ING
(
    PIATTO_ID INTEGER,
    INGREDIENTE_ID INTEGER,
    QTA_RICH INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY(PIATTO_ID, INGREDIENTE_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PIATTO_ID) REFERENCES PIATTO(PIATTO_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (INGREDIENTE_ID) 
        REFERENCES INGREDIENTE(INGREDIENTE_ID)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

How to get the plate's_id that satisfy all the required quantity for each ingredient ?!

to simplify the query I made a view table in which I joined three tables and their output is in the photo below...

I feel like this one should be easy, but sadly I have been stuck for hours.

[image]

Comment: you have three tables and two create table and a bad image, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a complete [mre] in textform

Comment: I guess that's a legit question with a great photo, I hope to be understood by people that can help me out with such a query, as for you giving me a thumbs down go ahead do whatever gives you kicks!

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using (`postgresql` or `mysql`) .

Comment: photos aren't aloowed see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: It's just the photo to have a visual-illustration aid of what the table view looks like, It doesn't have even one line of code in it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT piatto_nome FROM 'tablesname' WHERE qta_disp >= qta_rich
```

Hope it works

Comment: Doesn't work, it only prints out if each row's qta_disp is >= qta_rich

Comment: @MohamedMada  Isn't that what you want? If not, please clarify with an example output of what you want to see.

Comment: I just updated my question, please forgive my lack of clarification